# Any way to create a link to a custom setting's "manage" page?

Tags: visualforce, customsetting, urlfor

In a custom (Visualforce) setup page, I would like to provide links that open the "Manage" view for some of our custom settings.

Can `URLFOR` (or some other mechanism) provide such a URL? This also needs to work in Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply navigate to `Setup` > `Custom Settings`, and then copy the **Manage** link, it will look like below:

```
https://some-domain.my.salesforce.com/setup/ui/listCustomSettingsData.apexp?id=a02
```

So it should be fairly easy to generate programatically in Apex.

```
String relativePath = '/setup/ui/listCustomSettingsData.apexp';
String queryString = '?id=' + SObjectType.My_Setting__c.getKeyPrefix();
String manageUrl = URL.getOrgDomainUrl() + relativePath + queryString;
```

If you are creating this link in `Visualforce` and don't want to use Apex, I think it should still work using the `$ObjectType` global variable.

Comment: We have been burned a lot by this sort of URL hacking failing in Lightning so was wondering if there is a documented API approach.

Comment: @KeithC - if you've been burned by doing this programmtically in the past, can you store the URL for the custom setting in your custom setting (or another custom setting)?

Comment: A `Custom Label` would be more appropriate here if that sort of configurability is desired.

Answer (score 2):

Managing Custom Settings in Lightning are always a challenge in my view. I would suggest taking a look at what Salesforce.org does [here](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/master/src/pages/STG_SettingsManager.page) in the NPSP Package:

Basically, they created a wrapper VF page that then lets you navigate to each setting that lives in its own included VF page, and you can then edit/update with a simple shared controller. Yes, it is more overhead, but I just implemented it for someone else who had a bunch of settings for their managed package, and it provides a simple interface to update all custom settings.

Comment: Thanks for this; probably a bit too much work for my case but good to know.